# How to update projections in EF?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I am doing a projection using linq, the projection is supposed to convert my query data into an expected object, so I want to use automapper to edit my promotion object but automapper does not perform the operation.

```
       [HttpPut]
            public async Task<ActionResult> Put(Promocion promo)
            {
                Promocion proyeccion = await (from p in context.Promociones
                                           where p.PromocionId == promo.PromocionId
                                           select new Promocion
                                           {
                                               PromocionId = p.PromocionId,
                                               Nombre = p.Nombre,
                                               Descripcion = p.Descripcion,
                                               FechadeRegistro = p.FechadeRegistro,
                                               FechadeTermino = p.FechadeTermino,
                                               TipodePromociones = p.TipodePromociones,
                                               LugardeVisualizacion = p.LugardeVisualizacion,
                                               Activo = p.Activo,
                                               Mostrar = p.Mostrar,
                                               Idzona = p.Idzona,
                                               Zona = context.Zonas.Where(x => x.Idzona == p.Idzona).FirstOrDefault(),
                                               Imagenes = context.ImagenesCarruseles.Where(x => x.PromocionId == p.PromocionId).ToList()
                                           }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    
    
                if (proyeccion == null) { return NotFound(); }
    
                proyeccion = mapper.Map(promo, proyeccion);
                
                foreach (var item in promo.Imagenes)
                {
                    
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Imagen))
                    {
                        proyeccion.Imagenes = promo.Imagenes;
                    }
                }
    
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
              

  return NoContent();
        }
```

If I change my projection for another type of query, if it works, the problem is that I cannot use this alternative, I need to use the projection or if my projection query can be adapted to another form, I would appreciate it if you could help me the way I do the projection is wrong

this code does work:

```
[HttpPut]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Put(Promocion promo)
        {
            var promoDB = await context.Promociones
                .Include(x => x.Imagenes)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PromocionId == promo.PromocionId;

            if (promoDB == null) { return NotFound(); }

            promoDB = mapper.Map(promo, promoDB);
            
            foreach (var item in promo.Imagenes)
            {
                
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Imagen))
                {
                    promoDB.Imagenes = promo.Imagenes;
                }
            }

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return NoContent();
        }
```

Comment: But if the second version works then clearly AM has nothing to do with your problem, right? :) I mean, the AM code is the same.

Comment: I tested these two methods ,and the results are the same .It seems that there is no problem .But I don't understand the function of your `foreach` ,`mapper.Map(promo, promoDB)` has mapped `promo` to `promoDB` ,and `promoDB` has changed ,right?

Comment: And you did not update or add the `context` in the code ,why is the `SaveChangesAsyncoperation` performed ?Did you omit it in your question ?

Comment: Lucian Bargaoanu if AM is not the problem, it works fine if I do it as in the second way I posted the problem is my projection when I use it with AM, something is wrong there maybe because it is not an entity of the context

Comment: Chen, don't pay attention to foreach, it doesn't matter, my problem is my linq projection query for some reason automapper doesn't take it as a context entity and therefore I can't update it with automapper

Answer (score 1):

You can use automapper own ProjectTo method for any Queryable. For more information pls check this link **https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html**